# xml version in the build.xml in Ant build tools

Tags: ant, build

Can any one explain why we require the below line in the build.xml in the Ant build tools. And wat is the use of it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Actually xml contains of 1.0 and 1.1 version, the difference is 1.0 support the unicode characters. So Ant files are based on XML=1.0. So to specify the supported version, the above line is mentioned in the build.xml. Thanks